Is the difference between an unrecognizable language and a finite language decidable? recognizable?
Given 2 languages, A and B, such that A is not turing recognizable, B is finite, is it true that A-B is necessarily not turing recognizable?
I am studying to an exam and would appreciate your help! I think that the answer is "yes", but have no idea how to prove it.

Thank you for editing your post to focus on one question.  Please see our guidelines for asking questions about exercise-style problems: https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755.  I encourage you to [edit] your question to follow these guidelines.

The answer is "yes", this can be seen using a proof by contradiction.
Hint: All finite languages are recognizable and $\texttt{RE}$ is closed under union and intersection.

 All finite languages are turing recognizable, so $A \cap B$ must be turing recognizable as well.
 If we assume bwoc that $A - B$ is also recognizable, then $(A - B) \cup (A \cap B) = A$ must be recognizable as well ↯.

